# How to move files only if file and path exists?

Tags: shell, mv

I have wrote a command to only mv if file exists but its failing:

```
[ ! -f src/java/world.java ] || mkdir -p src/examples/ && mv src/java/world.java src/examples/world.java
```

Is there any option to check if path `src`, `src/java` and file exists?

Or just fail and keep returning zero

Answer (score 1):

While AND and OR lists (`list1 && list2` and `list1 || list2`) are appealing to make short code, they should only be used for simple tasks based on single commands. Anything else inhibits readability and maintainability of your code. In the  case of the OP, I would suggest to use a sime `if`-statement and write everything as

```
if [ -f /path/to/file ]; then
  mkdir -p -- /path/to/dir
  mv -- /path/to/file /path/to/dir
fi
```

This code is now very readable and states, *if file exists, then do some stuff*.

Complex combinations of AND and OR lists mainly lead to unexpected behaviour because the implementation made assumptions. A simple example is `cmd1 && cmd2 || cmd3`. Here `cmd3` is executed when `cmd1` OR `cmd2` returns a non-zero return-status and not only when `cmd1` returns false.

Answer (score 0):

Group your commands after the file check:

```
[ ! -f src/java/world.java ] || (mkdir -p src/examples/ && mv src/java/world.java src/examples/world.java)
```

Everything within the parenthesis will only be executed if src/java/world.java exists.

Example of this in action (note the srcX in the SOURCE parameter of mv:

```
$ [ ! -f src/java/world.java ] || mkdir -p src/examples/ ; mv srcX/java/world.java src/examples/world.java
mv: cannot stat 'srcX/java/world.java': No such file or directory
$ [ ! -f src/java/world.java ] || (mkdir -p src/examples/ ; mv srcX/java/world.java src/examples/world.java)
```

Since you're already checking for the full file path, then it doesn't really matter if src or src/java doesn't exist since world.java wouldn't exist in either case - unless you want to generate more appropriate errors.

Comment: yes but I don't want to raise an error case it fail...is possible to keep returning 0?

Comment: This code doesn't work

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: $ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
$ [ ! -f src/java/world.java ] || (mkdir -p src/examples/ && mv src/java/world.java src/examples/world.java)
$ echo $?                                                             0